# computing rolling slope on a large pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with > 250k rows and I'd like to compute rolling regression slopes. I can do it with the following code, but it takes over a minute. Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from scipy.stats import linregress

# Some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'y':np.random.normal(0,1,250000)})

def compute_slope(y):
    output = linregress(list(range(len(y))), y)
    return output.slope

start = datetime.now()
df['slopes'] = df['y'].rolling(window=15).apply(compute_slope)
print(f"Duration of rolling slopes = {datetime.now() - start}")

Out[12]: Duration of rolling slopes = 0:01:06.327182
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `np.polyfit` and `as_strided` you can do something like this:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

window = 15
ys = df.y.to_numpy()
stride = ys.strides

slopes, intercepts = np.polyfit(np.arange(window), 
                                as_strided(ys, (len(df)-window+1, window), 
                                           stride+stride).T,
                                deg=1)
```

Performance:

```
CPU times: user 148 ms, sys: 9.86 ms, total: 157 ms
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Even just using `np.polyfit()` it halves the runtime so that's good. However, when I actually use the strides as you posted it gives me way different slope values.

Comment: I tested it with `df = pd.DataFrame({'y': np.arange(32)})`, gives `slopes` all `1`. So I'm not sure where the problems are.

Comment: Note that this is shifted by `window`, remember how `rolling(window)` gives you `nan` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang, it does seem to be correct (my mistake!)

Comment: @QuangHoang great, would you mind explaing the meaning of stride+stride, or is it a must for your solution?